# Debugging PhantomJS webpage.open failures

Tags: phantomjs

In PhantomJS, webpage.open takes a callback with a status parameter that's set to 'success' or 'fail'.  According to the docs, it wll be "'success' if no network errors occurred, otherwise 'fail'."  Is there a way to see the underlying network error that caused the failure?

The url I'm trying to load works fine when I put it in my browser, and when I take a screenshot after getting the 'fail' message I see the page that I was on before I called webpage.open (so I can't just ignore the fail).  I'm using Phantom for testing, so ideally I'd like a robust way of easily getting a helpful error messsage when webpage.open fails (or better yet have it never fail!)

Comment: For future's sake: PhantomJS has not been maintained since 2017, and even when it were, some prominent sites misbehave under it. Headless Chrome is the way to go. With Node.js and puppeteer, even the API is reasonably close to the one PhantomJS provides.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Found this post which explains how to set up callbacks to get at the underlying reason for the failure: http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/getting-to-the-bottom-of-why-a-phantomjs-page-load-fails/

Based on the that page, you could print out errors as follows:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.error(resourceError.url + ': ' + resourceError.errorString);
};
```

The page goes on to show an example of detailed logging for phantoms

```
var system = require('system');

page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onResourceRequested()');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  request: ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onResourceReceived()' );
    system.stderr.writeLine('  id: ' + response.id + ', stage: "' + response.stage + '", response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onLoadStarted()');
    var currentUrl = page.evaluate(function() {
        return window.location.href;
    });
    system.stderr.writeLine('  leaving url: ' + currentUrl);
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onLoadFinished()');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  status: ' + status);
};

page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onNavigationRequested');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  destination_url: ' + url);
    system.stderr.writeLine('  type (cause): ' + type);
    system.stderr.writeLine('  will navigate: ' + willNavigate);
    system.stderr.writeLine('  from page\'s main frame: ' + main);
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onResourceError()');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  - unable to load url: "' + resourceError.url + '"');
    system.stderr.writeLine('  - error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + ', description: ' + resourceError.errorString );
};

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('= onError()');
    var msgStack = ['  ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace) {
        msgStack.push('  TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push('    -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function + '")' : ''));
        });
    }
    system.stderr.writeLine(msgStack.join('\n'));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you might want to outline info mentioned in the link in case info is removed, lost or changed